# Excel query join tables

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I have 4 tables reporting monthly sales of a product line; each table displays sales from a sdepcific channel (B2B, Ecommerce, Monobrand, Customized) and I'd like to stack these 4 tables one after the other.
Each table has the same exact columns, I can't do copy and paste because I need to update the 4 tables monthly.
I've tried to create a unique database and gather the information from the system throug a sequence of IF, IFS and SUMIFS but even though I get to the result, this takes forever in calculation

Is there a way to do it? I don't know, maybe with Powerquery or creating a Power Pivot?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the tables into Power Query and **append** them in the Combine section of the Home tab.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I did it, but as result I have the table I want, with alle the 4 tables appended one after another, but I also get all the 4 tables separately. How can I tell Excel to return me only the appended table?

Comment: Just delete the sheets that spit back out the input tables.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Another question. How do I update the results of the query? Because if I simply press the button "update" the computer works for a few seconds and then when it stops nothing happens. I've modified some values and ionserted a line in one of the 4 original tables but when I update the query nothing happens. How come?

Comment: Oh, don't mind. Obviously, if I modify the data in the original tables but do not save the file, the query will read the data at the last save. Saving the modified data I get the query results updated